# VBA function from a cell , pass variable

Tags: vba, function, variables

Im calling a VBA function from a cell and passing it a vaiable. However it is currently manually set .

```
=DevName(14)
```

Is there a way to set the (14) , to call the row that it is in ? Trying to prevent corruption of the formula if the use deletes a row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [ROW()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) function to get the current row of the cell:

```
=DevName(ROW())
```